# How do I make a DevExpress GridControl column fill remaining space in the grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, gridcontrol, devexpress-wpf

I have a `GridControl` where the first column is "Name", whose width I need to be variable, followed by several other columns whose width remains constant. If I was using the Telerik `DataGridView`, I would set the column width to `*`, but the DevExpress control doesn't allow that for the column width. It has no converter.

When the grid expands or contracts horizontally, I need the "Name" column to do the same, proportionately. Do I have to do this in code-behind? I really like my WPF basic CRUD to use as little code as possible.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used DevExpress for a while, but I think you can use for your 'Name' Column [GridColumn.BestFit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_BestFittopic)

For the rest, you can use [FixedWidth](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsOptionsColumn_FixedWidthtopic)